# SVG .. i want to fill it on the other sideof the path that i created

Tags: svg

so my project is to create a shape using path and lines, but the problem is I want to fill it a color inside not outside

so i have this code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g style="fill:none;stroke-width:4;">
/*head*/

<path d="M800,10
     Q650,100 500,10
     M300,260
     Q650,200 500,10
     M340,310
    C300,410
    225,280 300,260
    M550,550
    C600,400
    400,200 340,310
    M650,710
     Q630,600 550,550
     M1000,260
     Q650,200 800,10
     M960,310
    C1000,410
    1075,280 1000,260
    M750,550
    C700,400
    900,200 960,310
    M650,710
     Q670,600 750,550" style="stroke: #73b4d5; fill: Black;"/>


/*left-bone*/

    /*longest-bone*/

<line x1="600" y1="170" x2="630" y2="590"
      style="stroke: #006600;"/>

    /*shortest-bone*/

<path d="M570,540
    Q565,545 630,590" style="stroke: #28c628; fill: none;"/>

    /*top-bone*/

<path d="M470,260
    Q530,275 600,170" style="stroke: #76c628; fill: none;"/>

    /*side-bone*/

<path d="M570,540
    Q600,375 470,260" style="stroke: #28c66e; fill: none;"/>

/*right-bone*/

    /*longest-bone*/

<line x1="700" y1="170" x2="670" y2="590"
      style="stroke: #006600;"/>

    /*shortest-bone*/

<path d="M730,540
    Q735,545 670,590" style="stroke: #28c628; fill: none;"/>

    /*top-bone*/

<path d="M830,260
    Q770,275 700,170" style="stroke: #76c628; fill: none;"/>

    /*side-bone*/

<path d="M730,540
    Q700,375 830,260" style="stroke: #28c66e; fill: none;"/>

/*eyes*/

  <ellipse cx="650" cy="100" rx="70" ry="30" style="stroke:#73b4d5;fill:none;"/>

</g>    

</svg>
```

but when i run it the fill is outside the shape, what i want is to fill the shape inside not outside.

please help me! tnx a lot!

Comment: I already visited on this site, yet i cant find the answers, my problem is, if i fill the shape, the fill is formed outside the path, not inside

Comment: how do you fill the shape?  I am trying to do this myself....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that vector fills work like bitmap fills.  When you apply a flood fill in a bitmap editor, it'll fill the area enclosed by the connected lines.  Vector images don't work that way.

You can't just draw a series of individual touching path segments and expect the whole thing to combine to make a shape that can be filled.  A move (M) followed by a sequence of path commands (line, bezier etc) form a subpath.  Each subpath will be filled individually.  If you start a new subpath (ie with a move), you get a new filled shape.

If you want your "Head" shape to fill properly, you have to draw the entire shape with one contiguous boundary path.  Ie. just one M at the start.

Comment: I took your advise, and it works but my codes get harder, hehe by the way thanks!